# 2 labels on 4 in hypertext links

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My hypertext links are on all lines, I want to remove this hyperlink on "your previsous balance" and "your new balance"[image]

In HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let l of statementLines; let i = index">
   <td scope="col">
      <span *ngIf="l.dateOperation.length > 0">
      {{l.dateOperation | dateddmmyyyy | addleadingzeroesleft:'10'}}
      </span>
   </td>
   <td scope="col">
      <span *ngIf="l.dateOperation.length > 0">
      {{l.dateValue | dateddmmyyyy | addleadingzeroesleft:'10'}}
      </span>
   </td>
   <td scope="col">
      <a (click)="goToAnnexe(l); false;" href="#">
      {{l.libelle}}
      </a>
   </td>
   ...
```

My problem is here I think

```
<td scope="col">
      <a (click)="goToAnnexe(l); false;" href="#">
      {{l.libelle}}
      </a>
 </td>
```

In TS

```
goToAnnexe(annexe) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/portfolio/annexe/" + annexe.wholeLine.REFERENCEMOUV + "/" + annexe.wholeLine.NUM);
    console.log("text " + JSON.stringify(annexe));
}
```

I think the problem is with `libelle` but I don't see how to resolve it?

```
prepareDataForTemplate(res) {
    var libelle1 = this.translate.instant('5019');
    var libelle2 = this.translate.instant('5020');
    if (res.RETURNCODE == 'OKK00') {
        this.statementDate = res.OUTEXT.DATE;
        this.statementLines.push({
            dateOperation: "",
            dateValue: "",
            libelle: libelle1,
            sign: (res.OUTEXT.SOLD >= 0 ? '+' : '-'),
            amount: res.OUTEXT.SOLD,
            wholeLine: {
                REFERENCEMOUV: ""
            }
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES.length; i++) {
            this.statementLines.push({
                dateOperation: res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i]['DATEOPER'],
                dateValue: res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i]['DATEVALEUR'],
                libelle: res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i]['LIBELLE'],
                sign: (res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i].MONTANT > 0 ? '+' : '-'),
                amount: res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i].MONTANT,
                wholeLine: res.OUTEXT.MVMESPECES[i]
            });
        }
        this.statementLines.push({
            dateOperation: "",
            dateValue: "",
            libelle: libelle2,
            sign: (res.OUTEXT.SOLF > 0 ? '+' : '-'),
            amount: res.OUTEXT.SOLF,
            wholeLine: {
                REFERENCEMOUV: ""
            }
        });
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to check the l.libelle text value and conditionally return a hyperlink only if the value is not "your previous balance" or "your new balance"

```
<td scope="col">
   <ng-container *ngIf="l.libelle !== 'your previous balance' && l.libelle !== 'your new balance'; else elseNotDone">
     <a (click)="goToAnnexe(l); false;" href="#">
       {{ l.libelle }}
     </a>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-template #elseNotDone>
     <p>
       {{ l.libelle }}
     </p>
   </ng-template>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I just have a small problem, if I change the language it doesn't work anymore.

How would you integrate with `prepareDataForTemplate (res) {
 var libelle1 = this.translate.instant ('5019');
  var libelle2 = this.translate.instant ('5020');
          ...
`
I have to use libelle1 and libelle2

Comment: Inside your `this.statementLines.push({})` add a unique identifier like ID - ` this.statementLines.push({id: 1})` to each, then instead of checking by libelle in your ngIf statement, check by ID. I would advise this normally to be the better way